# KVO lost when entering background, trying to fix

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, key-value-observing

I have this method, adding an observer in **myViewController**:

```
-(void) observeSpeakerVolume{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"outputVolume" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}
```

I invoke this method in the viewdidLoad of **myViewController**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(observeSpeakerVolume) withObject:nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

and finally I monitor the observer as follows:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"outputVolume"]) {    
        if ([[change valueForKey:@"new"] isEqualToNumber:@0]){
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This all works fine, but as soon as my app is send to the background, eg by hitting the home button, the observer seems to be automatically removed.

To fix that, I do this in my AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    myViewController * wfc = [[myViewController alloc]init];
    [wfc observeSpeakerVolume];
}
```

That *seems* to work, however, switching back and forth several times between back- and foreground, eventually changing the volume of my iPhone crashes the app.

I tried to manually remove the observer when entering the background, but that also crashes the app, supporting the suggestion that the OS removes the observer automatically when entering the background.

So, I assume, that I'm adding the observer several times, but I don't see where, since ViewDidLoad is not called when the app enters the foreground.

What is wrong in my logic here?

thanks for your insights.

Comment: Do you remove the observer ever?  The appdelegate code doesn't do what you think it does, it's newing up another view controller of the same type and then throwing it away, it's not the same as the one shown on the screen.

Comment: I'm not sure if I want to remove the observer at all, since I need to be able to get the system volume at all times. What would be the moment to remove the observer then, and how would that help me reinstantiating the observer when it gets lost in the background?

Comment: The code you have written in your `applicationWillEnterForeground` is wrong, you are just initiating a new object and assigning observer which you are not using anywhere (An orphan object, which will eventually cause a crash). If you are not removing the observer anywhere in your code then the observer will be active always.

Comment: @Kevin & @ Midhun: I now see that the applicationWillEnterForeground code is wrong indeed. However, the question remains: how do I get my observer back after entering the foreground again?

Comment: @Sjakelien It should remain as Midhun mentions, are you sure you don't have some code somewhere that removes it?  Perhaps in viewDidDisappear?  Typically you'll see something like `removeAllObservers` called somewhere.

Comment: Nowhere in my code any observer is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but I had similar issue.

If you call

```
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
```

after your app is back from background e.g. in

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application;
```

then the observer will work again.